# Hint required for beginner

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract FunctionTest {
    bool public foo = true;
    string public name;
    uint256 public counter = 0;

    function setName() public {
        //
    }

    function writeToStorage() {
        foo = !foo;
    }

    function readFromStorageConstant() public constant returns (bool) {
        return foo;
    }

    function readFromStorageView() public view returns (bool) {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

I need to accomplish this: 
`Modify the function setName in a way that would allow setting the value of name`

How do I go about this? I have no clue as to how to proceed, any hints?

Comment: Sounds like homework you need to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what you mean by "setting the value of name"?

Comment: The key words are *function arguments* and *change state*. Don't give the answer, you need to go through by yourself

Comment: no @LauriPeltonen, not homework, I wish they gave solidity homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **bytes32** instead of **string**; it uses less gas because it fits in one 32 bytes storage slot (a.k.a word) while **string** is dynamically allocated, most "strings" that you're going to pass/use can fit in 32 bytes; so stick to that.
2. Initialize the value of your state variables inside of a **constructor**; constructors used to be a function that has the same name as the contract name, now (since Solidity 0.4.22 I think) you need to define them with the new keyword **constructor**.
3. Always declare visibility (public, private, internal, etc...); it's better for readability

Below is the modified contract (I also updated **setName** to your requirement):

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract FunctionTest {

    bool public foo; 
    //bytes32 instead of string
    bytes32 public name; 
    uint256 public counter;

    //Back in the day, constructors would have the same name as the contract (e.g. FunctionTest(){})
    constructor() public{
        //Initialize state variables here
        foo = true;
        counter = 0;
    }

    function setName(bytes32 _name) public {
        //Always validate input data
        require(_name > 0);
        name = _name;
    }

    function writeToStorage() public {
        foo = !foo;
    }

    function readFromStorageConstant() public constant returns (bool) {
        return foo;
    }

    function readFromStorageView() public view returns (bool) {
        return foo;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I was curious to know what advantage does the constructor give?